# User no longer anonymous after app restart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I start the app and sign the user anonymously with `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously()`.
The user gets an id, for example "`ABC`" and `isAnonymous` is true (obviously).

The problem is, when I restart (ctrl+shift+F5) an app, the user is still here (because data is persisted), he still has his previous id, except, `isAnonymous` is no longer true.

Why is he no longer anonymous after the app restart?

To summarize:

Sign in user anonymously **->** user gets an id and is anonymous **->** restart an app **->** the user is still here with his id but is no longer anonymous

Comment: How and when do you check that `isAnonymous` is false? After restarting the app it can take a little time while Firebase updates authentication information.

Comment: I use it in a `BlocBuilder`. I would understand if the user was null at first, but he is not, all his info is there and correct except `isAnonymous`. I'l ltry to subscribe to `authStateChanges` event.